# Change from acceleration (m/s^2) to velocity (m/s), replicating excel formula

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

I have a dataset which contains an acceleration and a time column. Within `excel` I can use these to create a velocity metric. However, I can't seem to replicate the formula in `R` as one step involves adding a cell to the previous cell in the data.

Within excel the formula is `H5 = H4+(G5*(B5-B4))` which is calculating a difference in time between readings(`B5-B4`), multiplying the result by acceleration (`G5*(B5-B4)`) then adding the results to the starting velocity value which is always zero.

The first two steps are fine but I haven't found how to replicate the third

```
data %>%
  mutate(
    Time_diff = Time - lag(Time),
    Accel_Time = Accel*Time_diff
  )
```

Here is the dataset with expected velocity column also, I've skipped ahead slightly in the data here as the first 100 or so rows have a zero velocity reading.

```
  > dput(head(data1, 20))
structure(list(Time = c(1.002, 1.004, 1.006, 1.008, 1.01, 1.012, 
          1.014, 1.016, 1.018, 1.02, 1.022, 1.024, 1.026, 1.028, 1.03, 
          1.032, 1.034, 1.036, 1.038, 1.04), Accel = c(-0.04, -0.04, -0.05, 
          -0.05, -0.04, -0.04, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.06, 
          -0.06, -0.06, -0.06, -0.06, -0.06, -0.06, -0.07, -0.06),          
          Velocity = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
          Time_diff = c(NA, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 
          0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002), 
          Accel_Time = c(NA, -0.0000800000000000001, -0.0001, -0.0001, 
          -0.0000800000000000001, -0.0000800000000000001, -0.0001, -0.0001, 
          -0.0001, -0.0001, -0.0001, -0.00012, -0.00012, -0.00012, -0.00012, -0.00012, -0.00012, -0.00012, -0.00014, -0.00012)), 
          row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any advice on this would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

constructing the example data frame:

`data1 <- data.frame(Time = c(1.002, 1.004, 1.006, 1.008, 1.01, 1.012, 1.014, 1.016, 1.018, 1.02, 1.022, 1.024, 1.026, 1.028, 1.03, 1.032, 1.034, 1.036, 1.038, 1.04), Accel = c(-0.04, -0.04, -0.05, -0.05, -0.04, -0.04, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.05, -0.06, -0.06, -0.06, -0.06, -0.06, -0.06, -0.06, -0.07, -0.06))`

1. computing the time lag - using 0 in the beginning and then simply subtracting 1st from 2nd, 2nd from 3rd and so on:

`data1$Time_diff <- c(0,data1$Time[-1] - data1$Time[-length(data1$Time)])`

2. computing `accel_time`:

`data1$accel_time <- data1$Time_diff * data1$Accel`

3. getting the cummulative sum of velocity:

`data1$velocity <- cumsum(data1$accel_time)`

one liner:
`cumsum(c(0,data1$Time[-1] - data1$Time[-length(data1$Time)]) * data1$Accel)`